# How to assess the stiffness of a hollow steel section joint?

Tags: structural-engineering, steel

Hollow steel sections are used often in trusses:

[image]

I've been taught that the advantage of a truss structure is that it can be stiff without any of the members being under bending moment. This is an advantage especially for the joints, which can now be designed nominally pinned.

In most structural codes, we categorize joints as rigid or pinned by comparing the stiffness of the joint to the stiffness of the connecting element. Eurocode for example gives an analytical method for calculating the stiffnesses of various beam-to-column end plate joints. However, I am interested in similar methods for hollow sections, especially RHS. Eurocode gives lot of info on how to calculate the axial resistance of these joints, but not their moment stiffness:

[image]

So my question is, how do we design such a steel truss joint to be pinned or rigid? I am mostly interested in design to Eurocode, but if other codes have more on this topic I would be interested in them also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content below is excerpted from the AISC360-16 Specification.

**HSS- HSS Truss (Pin) Connections**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**HSS- HSS Moment Connections**

[image]
[image]

This paper address the design of the RHS joints per Euro Code [DESIGN OF STRUCTURAL CONNECTIONS TO EUROCODE 3 - FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS](http://people.fsv.cvut.cz/%7Ewald/CESTRUCO/CESTRUCO_Engl_2003.pdf)

Here is a calculator per Euro Code 3 https://eurocodeapplied.com/design/en1993/rhs-design-properties

**ADD: Effect of joint rigidity verifications** (response to OP comment)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I’ll give that a vote.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting document. However I don't think the Eurocode document addresses my specific question about stiffness of the joints, it seems to cover only axial resistance calculation..

Comment: @S.Rotos I am not familiar with Eurocode, and I am afraid that I do not quite understand what is the "stiffness you are seeking", can you elaborate on it?

Comment: @r13 Ah, I did not mention this clearly, I am talking about rotational stiffness of a joint. In many codes we compare the calculated rotational stiffness of the joint to that if the connecting beam and use this ratio judge whether the connection is pinned or rigid. What I am interested in is how to calculate the rotational stiffness of a join between hollow elements. Eurocode provides this for I beam connections to column, but not between hollow elements.

Comment: I am not aware of any code that addresses the stiffness of the panel/truss joint. However, I've no doubt there are researches available, yet I wouldn't fully trust them nor apply them to real design. What you can do is perform two truss analyses using an analysis program, one conventional, one with flexural members connected by the rigid joints. Unless there are intermediate loads on the truss members, the results shall be close.  Note truss with member load (other than self-weight) is a rare event. Although an analysis on such case can verify the joint stiffness, it is rather meaningless.

Comment: Interesting. I can remember from simple physics class truss calculations that an assumption was made that no node carried moment. Also similar assumption was made when I took FE analysis in university. But you are saying this also occurs in practice and we could calculate without this assumption and still arrive at a solutiom where the moments are negligeable? Also what do you mean by member loads being rare? For example in roof truss, the nodes at the top carry the weight of the roof and several live loads.

Comment: @S.Rotos Practically yes. With joint loads only, the results will be 99.9% identical. That's the reason why, I believe, most of the codes adhere to the norm (what you have learnt in school) without addressing the stiffness of the joint as it does not matter.

Comment: @S.Rotos See the latest additions.

Comment: @S.Rotos Another notable is the "Vierendeel truss", it is a truss without diagonals, and the stability is maintained by moment joints.

Answer (score 0):

Assessing the stiffness of a hollow steel section joint typically involves evaluating the joint's structural behavior and calculating its stiffness characteristics. Here are some general steps to help you assess the stiffness of a hollow steel section joint:

Understand the joint type: Determine the specific type of joint you are working with, as different joint configurations have varying stiffness characteristics. Common types include welded connections, bolted connections, or a combination of both.

Gather information: Obtain relevant information about the joint, such as the dimensions and properties of the hollow steel sections involved, the connection type, and any additional components or reinforcement of [keytoinfo](https://keytoinfo.com/) present in the joint.

Analyze the joint geometry: Assess the geometry of the joint to understand how the hollow steel sections are connected. Consider factors such as the presence of welds or bolts, the arrangement of the joint, and any additional reinforcement used.